# How apply ko.utils.arrayGetDistinctValues on two dimensional arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, knockout.js

I have an ko.observableArray with two dimensions, i.e. "id" and "name".
Id will always be distinct, but name can hold the same value.

```
self.myArray = ko.observableArray( [ 
    { "id": "1", "name": "Barbara" }, 
    { "id": "2", "name": "Edwin"  }, 
    { "id": "3", "name": "Barbara" } 
] );
```

However I want to filter the array so that my result holds only the first occurrence of "name".

The result I want is:

```
self. myFilteredArray = [ 
    { "id": "1", "name": "Barbara" }, 
    { "id": "2", "name": "Edwin"  } 
];
```

I have been trying to figure this out using ko.utils.arrayGetDistinctValues(), but how can I utilize it on solely one chosen dimension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a computed for this:

```
viewModel.myFilteredArray = ko.computed(function() {
  var rv = [], names = [];
  for(var i=0; i<this.myArray().length; i++) {
    if(names.indexOf(this.myArray()[i].name) === -1) {
      rv.push(this.myArray()[i]);
      names.push(this.myArray()[i].name);
    }
  }
  return rv;
}, viewModel);
```

Comment: this is close to making my day. Uncertain if I should post it here or make a new question of it.

Thing is: myArray IRL has another dimension "type" which can be 0,1,2.

to get to "myArray" above I have already filtered it for this type with: function createTypeFiltered(myarray, type) {return ko.computed(function () {return ko.utils.arrayFilter(myarray, function (item) {return item.type() == type;});
 });}

self.myArray = createTypeFiltered(myInitialArrayContainingTypeAsWell(), 0);

How can I combine the two?

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest a function, that loops through the array, builds map of property values for each item and checks, whether the current value was already added. Something like this:

```
function filterByFirstOccurance(arr, prop) {
    var propValuesHash = {},
    result = [];
    for (var i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i++) {
        var item = arr[i],
            propValue = item[prop];
        if (item.hasOwnProperty(prop) && !propValuesHash[propValue]) {
            propValuesHash[propValue] = true;
            result.push(item);
        }
    }
    return result;
};
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/tLwJN/)

Comment: As far as I can see this will always return the first occurrence of the array, but only one item. Hence the result with the input above would be:  { "id": "1", "name": "Barbara" }.

Comment: @AsleG that is not correct. The fiddle example's output is just like your desired one.